# Выделить ссылку на которой находишься

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как выделить ссылку на текущую страницу (на которой находишься)? Знаю, что в интернете миллион примеров, но ничего не подходит. Может дело именно в моей структуре... Пробовала множество способов и `js` и `jquery`.

```html
<div class="cols col-10 af-1 bf-1 cblack tal bwhite p050 fs16 p12 bsbb">
  <div class="dib tdn clgray sort__navigation ">
    <span class="pr2 dib cblack p050">Показать:</span>
    <a href="/trenings/" class="pr2 dib p050">Все</a>
    <a href="/tag/prodazhi" class="pr2 dib p050">продажи</a>
    <a href="/tag/zakupki" class="pr2 dib p050">закупки</a>
    <a href="/tag/menedzhment" class="pr2 dib p050">менеджмент</a>
    <a href="/tag/upravlenie" class="pr2 dib p050">управление</a>
    <a href="/tag/obuchenie" class="pr2 dib p050">обучение</a>
    <a href="/tag/marketing" class="pr2 dib p050">маркетинг</a>
    <a href="/tag/mind-map" class="pr2 dib p050">mind map</a>
    <a href="/tag/peregovory" class="pr2 dib p050">переговоры</a>
    <a href="/tag/cenoobrazovanie" class="pr2 dib p050">ценообразование</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.sort__navigation a.pr2').each(function() {
  //console.log(window.location.href, this.href);
  if (window.location.href == this.href)
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cols col-10 af-1 bf-1 cblack tal bwhite p050 fs16 p12 bsbb">
  <div class="dib tdn clgray sort__navigation ">
    <span class="pr2 dib cblack p050">Показать:</span>
    <a href="/js" class="pr2 dib p050">Snippets</a>
    <a href="/trenings/" class="pr2 dib p050">Все</a>
    <a href="/tag/prodazhi" class="pr2 dib p050">продажи</a>
    <a href="/tag/zakupki" class="pr2 dib p050">закупки</a>
    <a href="/tag/menedzhment" class="pr2 dib p050">менеджмент</a>
    <a href="/tag/upravlenie" class="pr2 dib p050">управление</a>
    <a href="/tag/obuchenie" class="pr2 dib p050">обучение</a>
    <a href="/tag/marketing" class="pr2 dib p050">маркетинг</a>
    <a href="/tag/mind-map" class="pr2 dib p050">mind map</a>
    <a href="/tag/peregovory" class="pr2 dib p050">переговоры</a>
    <a href="/tag/cenoobrazovanie" class="pr2 dib p050">ценообразование</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Пробовала, не добавляется класс (

Comment: @АннаМатвеева `console.log(window.location.href, this.href);` - ?

Comment: @Igor Да, показывает те ссылки, которые нужны

Comment: @BearVorkuta консоль показывает ошибку ссылки

Comment: @АннаМатвеева Добавьте в вопрос содержимое консоли - `console.log(window.location.href, this.href, window.location.href == this.href);`.

Comment: Добавила ( если добавить еще window.location.href == this.href); то в конце на всех строчках дописывается false)

Comment: @АннаМатвеева Видно же, что строки отличаются на слеш в конце. Сделайте сравнение с учетом этой разницы.

Comment: Да, все верно, спасибо большое!

Comment: @АннаМатвеева Пожалуйста. Успехов.